# JSON object to byte array

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka

If I have a JSON object , and want to convert it to a byte stream (for Kafka ) is it always the case that the JSON object gets converted to a String and encoded as UTF-8 (or other) bytes. Do all libraries do this internally ?

Comment: JSON _is_ strings. Technically "JSON object" is not really correct, it's just slang for a JSON string that parses into an object. So yes, you're right, you can convert the JSON string into UTF-8 using any suitable library.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question, but isn't JSON always a string? When you serialize JSON, you are effectively taking a class full of data and converting it to JSON. When you deserialize, it is the opposite. So are you really asking how to transfer a string through a bytestream?

Comment: @Ray Toal cy-c Not sure what am I missing but why is JSON a string ? We typically stringify a JSON object right ? I tried to keep the q as simple as possible but what i was getting to was : if all algorithms that optimize the serialization eventually end up converting a JSON object to a string and then encode , what exactly is the optimization ?

Comment: JSON is a *notation* of a Javascript Object. In order to *serialize it*, it is sent as UTF-8 bytes. Any deserializer or parser accepts a String as well, then converts into an Object. There is no "optimization"; only that you need a way to send the payload "over the wire" or "in memory"

Comment: JSON is a notation, like XML, YAML, etc. It is a way to represent objects as strings. For example the string `{"x": 1}` is a JSON representation -- a string -- of an object. You **parse** that JSON string into an object (hash in Ruby, dict in Python, etc.) Given a JS object, Ruby hash, Python dict, etc., you **stringify** that _into a string in the JSON format_. Now since JSON is a string representation, you can **serialize** the string using an encoding like UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 to obtain a sequence of bytes. Hope that helps.

Comment: you can just use Kafka with `value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` or JsonSerializer/Deserializer and usually string, and json is a string, are already UTF-8 normally.